# How do I get the path of the container folder of a file?

Tags: applescript

I want to pass the path of the containing folder of a file to a command `make new file at path`. I know how to get the path of the currently open file (with `tell application "TexShop" to set thePath to get path of document 1`), but I don't know how to get the path of the containing folder.

I tried using `container of`, like this:

`tell application "TeXShop"
    set thePath to get container of path of document 1
end tell`.

But I get this error:
`TeXShop got an error: Can’t make container of path of document 1 into type reference.`

Is that because while the container command is allowed in the application Finder it is not for the application TeXShop?

Comment: You need to look at the scripting dictionary (if any) to see the specific terms that are provided.  `container` is from the Finder, it would just be a coincidence if the same term provided the same functionality in another app.

Comment: I provided a direct solution yesterday at your other almost identical post  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58106617/6844169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following AppleScript code will get the path to the front most document in the front most application and the path to its containing folder. This will also create the new file in the containing folder.

```
(* The Delay Command  Gives You Time To Bring The Desired App To The Front
    Mainly For Use While Testing This Code In Script Editor.app *)

delay 5 -- Can Be Removed If Not Needed

tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to ¬
    set documentPath to (get path of document 1) as POSIX file as alias

tell application "Finder" to set containingFolder to container ¬
    of documentPath as alias

tell application "Finder" to make new file at containingFolder
```

Comment: Finder can make a new file at the containing folder, but oddly, TexShop, which has the command "make" and the option "at location specifier", does not. It receives the error "cannot make into type location specifier". Do you know what kind of location specifier would be standard for an application like TexShop? I have also tried using "alias [some path]" and received the same error or the error "File alias X wasn't found." Thank you.